# Create aiu_trigger , table can be modified by several users

Tags: oracle, triggers, apex

I  am in the process of implementing a trigger, which is triggered as soon as a change occurs in table 1.
The first user in this case is a student, who can edit this table using a form.
The trigger then records in a so-called AUDIT table who has done what and when in the form intended for them.
However, I have the following problems:

- A person can be selected as responsible for several forms
- However, if this person edits the table or the form intended for him, the action carried out should only be recorded for this form.
  At the moment, however, the trigger looks to see in which forms this person is entered as the responsible person and logs it for all the rows it finds.

  ```
  create or replace TRIGGER TRG_AUDIT_TBL1
    -- starts on every update or insert command
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TBL1
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    v_user varchar2(30);
    v_userid USERS.UUID%TYPE;
    v_done_action varchar2(50);
    v_stud_id STUDENTS.ID%TYPE;
    v_resp RESPONSIBLE.ID%TYPE;


    v_form_id form.id%TYPE;
    does_exist number;


    BEGIN
    v_user := SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER');
    select UUID into v_userid from users where lower(username)=lower(v_user);

    select count(*) into does_exist
    from STUDENTS
    where uuid in (select UUID from users
    where uuid=v_userid);

    if (does_exist>0)
    then
    select STUID into v_stud_id from students where uuid = v_userid;
    end if;

    select count(*) into does_exist
    from respsonsible
    where uuid in (select UUID from users
    where uuid=v_userid);

    if (does_exist>0)
    then
    select r.ID, f.ID into v_resp,v_form_id from RESPONSIBLE r left outer join forms f on r.respid=i.ID
    where r.uuid = v_userid ;
    end if;



    IF :NEW.STATE ='REQUESTED' then
    v_done_action :='test123';

    ELSIF :NEW.STATE ='APPROVED_BY_RESP' THEN
    v_done_action :='test1234.';

    ELSIF :NEW.STATE ='DENIED_BY_RESP' THEN
    v_done_action :='test12345.';

    ELSIF :NEW.STATE ='CHANGE_REQUEST_BY_RESP' THEN
    v_done_action :='test123456.';

    END IF; 

    IF ( v_stud_id = :NEW.STUID) or
    ( v_resp=:NEW.RESPID) and
    (:OLD.STATE <>:NEW.STATE) then


    INSERT INTO AUDIT_TBL1
    (FORMID,DONE_ACTION,COLUMN1,STATE)
    VALUES
    (:NEW.ID,v_done_action,:NEW.COLUM1,:NEW.STATE);
    END IF;

    END;
  ```

So I wonder if it is somehow possible to say that an insert on the AUDIT_TBL1 table should only happen for the row in which the ID of table 1 is the same as the ID that is edited by the person responsible. Or in other words make an insertion into AUDIT_TBL1 where updated/edited tbl1 id equals id in table 1.
I know the code is far from perfect, but I would be grateful if this question in particular could be clarified.

### I've been stuck here for a very long time and would really appreciate any help:)

The row which the person responsible is currently changing in table1(form table) is shown in colour.
[image: Form Table]

The trigger is then fired, but as you can see, it also makes an entry for the row that was not changed by the person responsible, but for which he he is entered as the person responsible.
[image: False Audit Table]

However, I would rather like this case to occur

[image: How it should be]

Only one entry is made in the audit table for the row that has just been changed by the person responsible.

In this case in particular, the question is whether it is possible in APEX to find out which row is currently being modified and get the value of a certain column (here Form ID) and then to make an entry in the audit table only for this value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't figure out quite what you want to happen or what problem you are having with your current code.  You say that currently the code logs multiple rows of data.  But the code you're showing has an `insert into audit_tbl1 (...) values (...)` statement which, by definition, would only insert 1 row and no other way to insert data into the audit table.  It would be very helpful if you could provide some sample data and some `insert` and `update` statements that show what your application is doing and tell us what you would want to be logged for each statement.

Comment: Architecturally, my initial guess is that you really want this logic to be part of your application where you have more context about what is going on rather than putting it in a trigger.

Comment: You are right I was a bit unclear, what I mean is that if a person is selected as responsible for several forms and this person only processes one form (i.e. one row in table 1), the trigger logs this in AUDIT_TBL1 for all rows in which the person is specified as responsible.

Comment: But the only statement that writes to `audit_tbl1` in the trigger you posted is 1) an `insert ... values` that can only ever insert a single row and 2) missing all the code for what is being inserted.  That makes it very, very difficult for anyone to guess at what is actually happening.  If you are saying that multiple rows are being written to `audit_tbl1`, that would at least potentially imply that multiple rows of `tbl1` are being modified.  Maybe unintentionally.  Again, sample data and sample DML on `tbl1` would be awfully helpful.

Comment: This is also only one line that is inserted, but this line should only log for the row currently being processed in table 1 and not all rows for which the person is entered as responsible.

Comment: In general, can you specify which row has just been edited in an after insert trigger?

Comment: Your trigger has a single `insert ... values` statement.  It has no loop.  Therefore, each execution of the trigger must, by definition, insert at most 1 row in the audit table.  There is no way that an update of a single row would write two rows to the audit table.  You can use the `:new.id` to see the `id` of the `tbl1` row that is being modified.  But if you are seeing two rows in the audit table, the trigger is getting called twice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments very hard to understand what you are trying to do from the information that you have provided. But gonna take a shot in the dark....
You say that a person can be responsible for multiple forms so it looks to me this code should be failing at the below...

```
  if (does_exist>0) then
    select r.ID, f.ID 
    into v_resp,v_form_id 
    from RESPONSIBLE r 
    left outer join forms f on r.respid=i.ID
    where r.uuid = v_userid ;
  end if;
```

If the user has either multiple responsibilities or multiple forms then this is going to get a too_many_rows error. Not the symptom you are describing but what I believe would happen with the code you have posted.

My Guess as to what you would have to do to fix it would be add some where conditions to the above select specifiying the responsibility / form (I can only assume these are recorded in TBL1 so can be accessed using :NEW.Fieldname)

Comment: I edited the question and have filled it with sample data. I have already tried this possibility, which you describe. As you said, it spits out a too many row error.
I'm not quite sure how to tell apex to choose only the FORMID that is currently being edited by the person responsible. This can work around the error, because it would only spit out one value..

Comment: the case has been solved and you were right it was not the trigger but a function. it did an update on a column in table 1 every time the person changed something. the update had no condition so it updated all rows and the trigger logged it logically. I apologise for the unnecessary questions and thank you for your suggestions!